# Apache Beam API to Runner instruction translation

Tags: apache-beam

**Input**: A sentence 
**Expected Output**: String representation of an array generated by `line.split(' ')`

**Transformation defined**

```
.apply(
            MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                .via((String line) -> Collections.singletonList(line.split("[^\\p{L}]+")).toString()))
```

**Question**:
Does Beam translate the above instruction wherein I'm using a toString() to runner based implementations of toString? I want to avoid defining inadvertently a UDF that might cause subpar performance (I come from background in Spark, Pig) . I'm little hazy on how the translation happens between beam API and Runner instructions; appreciate any resources that throw light on the translation.

Answer (score 0):

No, Beam runners should not update that function. `MapElements` is implemented using a Beam `ParDo` that will execute your function on incoming data as is. Beam runners may fuse multiple steps to create fused steps. Also the performance might depend on the Jvm used by the Beam runner.